# How to recreate JDK tar.gz file after added a certificate

Tags: java, jenkins, tar

My organization requires all JDK to include a specific certificate.

I therefore followed these steps:

1. downloaded the JDK as jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz (170M)
2. unzip jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz
3. Added our certificate using keytool
4. created a new tarball jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz from the extracted contents (300M)

I then uploaded the new tarball to our Jenkins server, but I receive the following error:

```
    ERROR: Failed to download https://xxxx/jdk-17-linux-x64.tar.gz from agent; will retry from master
java.io.IOException: incorrect header check
    at com.jcraft.jzlib.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:168)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.readRecord(TarArchiveInputStream.java:459)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.getRecord(TarArchiveInputStream.java:428)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.getNextTarEntry(TarArchiveInputStream.java:305)
    at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2582)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to extract input stream
    at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2608)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$500(FilePath.java:211)
    at hudson.FilePath$Unpack.invoke(FilePath.java:954)
```

I realized the new tar.gz I created is 300M in size, much larger than the 170M of the original tar ball.

Can someone please let me know how to recreate a proper JDK tarball? Maybe I should use a specific compression format?

Comment: Instead of shipping the entire JDK, can you ship the keystore alone?

Comment: What tar command do you use ?

Comment: Could you please add the precise commands you use to unpack/pack your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception message, it looks like the file that Hudson is trying to extract is not a valid `tar.gz` file.  As the regenerated file is roughly the same size as the *uncompressed* file tree, my guess is that you have missed out the compression step when creating the file; i.e. you have created an *uncompressed* TAR file.

A proper `tar.gz` file is a TAR file that has been compressed using gzip compression.  You can create one like this:

```
$ tar -cfz my_jdk.tar.gz ....
```

or like this:

```
$ tar -cf my_jdk.tar ....
$ gzip my_jdk.tar
```

Refer to the manual entries for more details; e.g. read `man tar` and / or `man gzip`.